# Cannot access 2>&1: How to treat variable content as a redirection not as filename

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

How can I control process output redirection based on variable content? I have tried following but it treats content of `$redirect` as a file name instead of redirection itself.

```
$ redirect="2>&1 >/dev/null"
$ ls -la $redirect
ls: cannot access 2>&1: No such file or directory
$ redirect=""
$ ls -la $redirect
total 376
drwx------ 1 wakatana users   4096 Feb  5 15:32 .
drwx------ 1 wakatana users   4096 Feb  2 18:44 ..
-rw------- 1 wakatana users    390 Feb  5 13:34 .bashrc
```

Comment: You can't do this as such. The order of evaluations doesn't work that way. You *can* use `eval` to force this but you don't want to. It isn't safe or a good idea.

Comment: When Bash expands the variable `redirect`, all operators have already been scanned. See [how Bash processes what it reads](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation). So the `2>&1` is not interpreted as a redirection here, but just as a mere argument.

Comment: Note what code frenzy is mentioning too. You redirect stderr to point to what stdout is pointing to, and then redirect stdout to /dev/null. This will _not_ redirect stderr to /dev/null ! It's interpreted from left to right in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve what you want, provided you accept to change the order of your command: use an alias. Aliases are usually frowned upon, and, as stated in the Bash manual, *For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.*

It seems we're here in the *almost* breach:

```
$ alias redirect='2>&1 > /dev/null'
$ redirect ls
$
```

And no `eval`.

Comment: Order of redirections is inverted as per comments on the OP.

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't see where OP mentions he wants to redirect stdout to `/dev/null` and stderr to terminal.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that he didn't but the *vast* majority of the time redirection of this sort is an error (especially from people unfamiliar with the shell). Also you said "(no output, everything is redirected to `/dev/null`)" which isn't what it does. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, I got that part messed up!

Comment: Why can't you use a function? `redirect() { (exec 2>&1 1>/dev/null; "$@") }`. (And I'm not convinced by the redirect order. OP's order captures stderr while sending stdout to the bit bucket, which can certainly be useful. `ls "${files[@]}" 2>&1 1>/dev/null`)

Comment: @rici: your function executes the command in a subshell. This may be unwanted if we're redirecting the output function that has side effects like setting variables. Then `redirect() { 2>&1 > /dev/null "$@"; }` certainly works but, when I wrote this, I had in mind to preserve, as much as possible, the syntax of OP. In this case, defining an alias is (arguably) easier than defining a function, especially if OP wants to modify `redirect` often.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: yeah, mine won't work for builtins like `read`. I'd considered the non-exec version; it probably would have been better. But neither of these nor the alias allow you to put `redirect` at the end of the command-line as in the OP, so I'm not sure what the influence of the original syntax might be on the choice. The alias is less typing, to be sure; but the function might use some other tricks to allow simple reconfiguration.

Comment: @rici: add an answer with your function solution! (or edit an existing one).

Answer (score 3):

The `ls` error happens because the shell scans for redirections before it performs parameter expansion (and you might think about the sequence of redirections as well) and tries to list two files named `2>&1` and `>/dev/null`, much like if you had typed `ls '2>&1' '>/dev/null'`. The way to do what you want is to have a second iteration of all the redirections and substitutions. The `eval` builtin does just that:

```
 eval ls -la $redirect
```

If you must know, the order according to [the POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) is

1. The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to Shell Grammar Rules are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.
2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections shall be
   expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the first
   field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are
   the arguments for the command.
3. Redirections shall be performed as described in Redirection.
4. Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and
   quote removal prior to assigning the value.

Here's an example with a less complex redirection to illustrate what is going on:

```
$ redirect=">file"
$ echo foo $redirect
foo >file
$ eval echo foo $redirect
$ cat file
foo
```

As Etan points out, `eval` may not be a suitable solution if you don't control the exact contents of `redirect`. Imagine what `redirect='; rm -rf $HOME'` can do.

Comment: Bash doesn't perform parameter substitutions before parameter substitutions. See [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation): point 4 (expansion) appears before point 5. You can actually do the experiment: `set -u; echo "$a" > test`: you'll see that, if variable `a` is unset, the file `test` will not be created.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks for pointing that out. I have modified the wording accordingly and replaced "performs redirections" with "scans for redirections" which is hopefully closer to what POSIX step 1 dictates.

Answer (score 1):

Order of `2>&1` needs to be reversed, change:

```
$redirect="2>&1 >/dev/null"
```

to

```
$redirect=">/dev/null 2>&1"
```

edit:

To run `ls -al` on command line, a better alternative would be to do:

```
$redirect="ls -al >/dev/null 2>&1"
eval $redirect
```

Purpose of putting `2>&1` in the end is to redirect all errors generated by the command as well as first redirection.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Did you test what you wrote?